# Select all information from a table that has SOME status=0 in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in MySQL database

```
account | status
1       |   1
1       |   0
1       |   0
2       |   0
2       |   0
2       |   0
3       |   1
3       |   1
3       |   1
```

How do I SELECT from this table all information where some status for the account is equal to zero? In this example, the result should be

```
account | status
1       |   1
1       |   0
1       |   0
2       |   0
2       |   0
2       |   0
```

since for account.name=3 all statuses are 1.

Thanks,
Vladimir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select account, status
from tab
where account in (select account 
                  from tab 
                  where status = 0)
```

[**Sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d097/2/0)

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan It is! above :)

Comment: yeah. There you go :)

Comment: @VolodymyrKruglov here you are :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE `account` IN 
(SELECT `account` FROM Table1 WHERE `status` = 0)
```

---

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa2f7f/1)

---

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` version:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
  join (select distinct account
        from tablename
        where status = 0) t2
  ON t1.account = t2.account
```

(ANSI SQL syntax, but I suppose it works for MySQL as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Write a subquery that finds all the accounts with `status = 0`, and join that with the table.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM YourTable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT account
      FROM YourTable
      WHERE status = 0) AS t2
ON t1.account = t2.account
```

In MySQL, this is likely to perform better than the `IN` queries in the other answer. MySQL doesn't optimize those very well.